# How to check the url is classic or Lightining

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have written code in apex class ,I want to check the url belongs to classic or Lightining

```
string UrlDomainName  = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
             if(classicView)
            {
               // classic code
            }
            else
            {
                // lightining code
            }
```

> what i have to write instead of classic view for  finding classic
>   url,please anyone help me to rectify this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

URL checking is not ideal way of detecting user's current mode. There is a better way.

```
UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed();
```

This method returns a string from the following list.

> Theme1—Obsolete Salesforce theme
>
> Theme2—Salesforce Classic 2005 user interface theme
>
> Theme3—Salesforce Classic 2010 user interface theme
>
> Theme4d—Modern “Lightning Experience” Salesforce theme
>
> Theme4t—Salesforce mobile app theme
>
> Theme4u—Lightning Console theme
>
> PortalDefault—Salesforce Customer Portal theme
>
> Webstore—Salesforce AppExchange theme

Theme3 should be classic and Theme4d is for LEX. [More details here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm).

```
if(UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed() == 'Theme3')
{
//classic code
}
else if(UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed() == 'Theme4d')
{
// LEX code
}
```